# problems with the insertion of data by json to postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql

I do not understand why my code does not add the data from the JSON that I have created in appscript, I execute certain sections individually, for example I print all the JSON and it prints it well, then the database connection gives me correct even list the data entered in the postgres, what is the error in my code
problems with the insertion of data by json to postgresql

```
const { Client } = require('pg');
const fetch = require('node-fetch').default;

const obtenerItinera = async () => {
  const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'pruebas',
    password: '123456',
    port: 5432,
  });

  await client.connect();

  const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM datos_generales');
  const result = res.rows;

  await client.end();

  return result;
};

const insertarDatos = async (data) => {
  const client = new Client({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'pruebas',
    password: '123456',
    port: 5432,
  });

  await client.connect();

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const row = data[i];

    // Verificar si la fila ya existe en la base de datos por su valor de vuelo
    try {
      const res = await client.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM datos_generales WHERE vuelo = $1', [row.vuelo]);
      const count = parseInt(res.rows[0].count);

      if (count === 0) {
        // La fila no existe en la base de datos, realizar la inserción
        console.log('Insertando fila:', row);

        await client.query(`INSERT INTO datos_generales (vuelo, eta, etd, ata, atd) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`, [row.vuelo, row.eta, row.etd, row.ata, row.atd]);
        console.log('Fila insertada:', row);
      } else {
        console.log('La fila ya existe en la base de datos, omitiendo inserción:', row);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al realizar la inserción:', error);
    }
  }

  const res = await client.query('SELECT * FROM datos_generales');
  const result = res.rows;

  await client.end();

  return result;
};

async function downloadJSON() {
// el link fue cortado
  const url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/exec'; // Reemplaza con la URL real tu API

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    // Insertar los datos en la base de datos
    const resultadoInsercion = await insertarDatos(data);
    console.log('Datos insertados:', resultadoInsercion);

    // Realizar la consulta SELECT * después de agregar los datos
    const resultadoConsulta = await obtenerItinera();
    console.log('Datos obtenidos:', resultadoConsulta);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al descargar el JSON o insertar los datos:', error);
  }

  // Programar la próxima descarga después de 5 segundos
  setTimeout(downloadJSON, 5000);
}

// Iniciar la descarga inicial
downloadJSON();
```

I was expecting all the JSON to be added to my DATABASE I have checked the names, data types and nothing

Comment: I don't see where you `commit` the `insert`. See [transactions](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions).

Comment: Simplify your testing: write a new file that connects to the database and _only_ performs a single, hardcoded, insert. If that works, compare it to this code to see what you did differently, and if that _doesn't_ work, you should show that new, [much smaller, code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your post instead.